# Why won't trigger events work in my phantomjs script?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, ui-testing

I am writing some automated ui tests for a single page wizard style form that I am building. I am trying to simulate a keyup on a particular input element but the .trigger jquery method doesn't seem to work. This is what I have.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';



page.open('http://localhost:6543/signup', function (status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } 
    else {

        var test = page.evaluate(function () {

            //entersnumber
            $('#number').val('2223443');
            //keyup triggers ajax call validating that number is not already in the db
            $('#number').trigger('keyup');
            //the radio button is clicked
            $('input:radio[name=salesBroker]').filter('[value=0]').click();

        });

        page.render('thing.png')        
    }

    phantom.exit();
});
```

The keyup is important because it will trigger an ajax call to check if the number exists. When I look at the thing.png image the validation error is not showing. This means that the keyup is not being triggered.

the image being saved:

[image]

If the keyup works there should be a validation error showing.

Comment: What happens if you use native `page.sendEvent` method, like described [here](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=760)?

Comment: I looked at that and havn't tried it, but the keyup event needs to target the #number dom element. The page.sendEvent seems to by for general events not targeting the dom.

Comment: Erm... can't `focus()` be used to target this element (as in the example by the link)?

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb. Didn't see the link before. It worked great.

Comment: Ok, glad to help. Should I make this an answer? )

Comment: Yeah make it an answer. What I was misunderstanding was that evaluate happens within the context of the page. The sendEvent method just sends inputs without any thought of what is loaded on the page. The focus needs to happen before you can send an event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one should use a slightly different approach for triggering keyboard-related events: first set focus at a specific input, then call [**page.sendEvent**](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) method with the relevant params:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    $('#number').val('2223443').focus();
});
page.sendEvent('keyup', someKey);
```

By the way, that's a fairly new feature - it debuted in [version 1.7](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.7.html).

Comment: Can the event triggering be done within the `page.evaluate`. I need to interact multiple times within the page sandbox and i don't want to get out of `page.evaluate` everytime.